# The app back to previous page when I attempt to fetch data from another activity

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-activity

I have 1 adapter file, contain following code:

```
//When user click detailBtn, it will pass the data to EventDetail page.
        holder.detailBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(holder.detailBtn.getContext(), EventDetail.class);
                intent.putExtra("eventName", datalist.get(position).getEventName());
                intent.putExtra("eventDate", datalist.get(position).getEventDate());
                intent.putExtra("eventVenue", datalist.get(position).getEventVenue());
                intent.putExtra("eventDesc", datalist.get(position).getEventDesc());
                intent.putExtra("eventRole", datalist.get(position).getEventRoles());
                intent.putExtra("eventCreator", datalist.get(position).getEventCreator());

                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                holder.detailBtn.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

**The main problem occur here, following code is caused the problem:**:

So, when I try to access the field "eventRole" and put it in ArrayAdapter in *EventDetail* java file using following code:

```
String[] roles = (String[]) getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("eventRole");
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.option_item, roles);
```

The app **jump back to previous page** :(
Can anyone help me to look into why it return back to previous activity when I try to access it? I can't find any clue on the logcat it shows to me...

The "eventRole" array is stored as Map Structure in Firestore.

[image: Logcat result]

[image: Structure of firestore]

[image: New Logcat result]

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: @AlexMamo Added.

Comment: Please also indicate also at which line of code it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your `getEventRoles()` method return String[] ? As far as I understood, you have casted `getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("eventRole");` to String[] even if `getStringArrayExtra()` **is returning String[]**, Why ?

I think the problem is in your `getEventRoles()` method, it might not be returning String[] and you are trying to **cast that incompatible type to String[] which is throwing `ClassCastException`**.

Comment: Yes, my `getEventRoles()` method return String [] inside my EventModel with the following code:
`public String[] getEventRoles() {
        return eventRole;
    }

    public void setEventRoles(String[] eventRole) {
        this.eventRole = eventRole;
    }
    public EventModel(){}
    public EventModel(String[] eventRole){
        this.eventRole = eventRole;
}
`

Comment: Please show line 115 of EventDetail.java

Comment: `String[] roles = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("eventRole");`

Comment: @RAHIL This line, I also mentioned in the main question.

Comment: Check if your `getIntent()` is returning `null` or not!

Comment: Sorry, the `getIntent()` return this: `getIntent: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.myvolunteer/.EventDetail (has extras) mCallingUid=10388 }`

Comment: But, `getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("eventRole")` return null. I am not sure why this happen.

Comment: if `getStringArrayExtra("eventRole")` is returning null then don't cast it in **String[]**. Try removing the cast.

Comment: Already removed, but it still keep returning null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237478/discussion-between--and-pi-pi-nan).

Comment: Okay, I already reply in the chat.